# drawerlayout com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, xml

i was following the navigation drawer training on android developers and the layout is causing an error and i added the support library so am not sure what is causing the problem

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="frag_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transperant"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing the second occurrence of `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in the opening DrawerLayout tag. Also, you've misspelled `transparent` in the ListView's `divider` attribute. And the `id` for your FrameLayout is incorrect.

Comment: thanks for helping but there is still an error android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout could not be found and i have it imported in my project.